# PermissionError [Error no 13] on Python | Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, flask, file-permissions

So, I'm making a website using Flask where a user can upload information to the server. I have an HTML form that takes an image and transfers it to the server. On the server side, I'm running this function:

```
def upload(file, directory):
    file.filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    path = os.path.join(os.getenv("UPLOAD_FOLDER"),directory)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path, mode=0o777)
    file.save(path)
```

As it is in here, the expected output would be the creation of a directory and, inside it, a file which I pass to the function. The directory is created normally, but when the file needs to be added, the obtained output is `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\[...]\\images\\directory'` (where images is a pre-existing folder and directory is the newly created one).

I've looked around in other similar questions and the documentation which hinted the usage of os.chmod() and umask, but my attempts in using them didn't change the situation.

I use PyCharm to run the server, and tried running it as Administrator as well to no avail.

Comment: Whatever you are hoping to accomplish mode 0777 is ***wrong* and *dangerous.***

Comment: Trying to apply the Unix file permission model on Windows is probably not going to work very well anyway. Does your code actually have to run on Windows?

Comment: Mode 0o777 was just one of the tests I've been trying and I've deleted afterwards. All I want to do is have a file created on a directory. The site is built for Windows so far and the tests are being run there. Should I consider using Docker to get around the issue?

Comment: If you want Unix semantics and are not willing to ditch Windows entirely, running a virtualized Unix-like system is one way, yes.